# Java GUI Programming ActionListener

Tags: java

I'm learning Java GUI Programming from Murach's Java with Netbeans book...I have read that an interface cannot be instantiated using the 'new' keyword instead a class that implements the interface can be instantiated...In the image below on the highlighted lines the 'new' keyword is used with the ActionListener INTERFACE..How is this possible?? Is an object of ActionListener being created?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `new ActionListener()` creates an [annonymous inner class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) of the type `ActionListener`. but `ActionListener` is an interface, that's why you can not simply create a new instance like `Object obj = new Object();`. You have to implement the methods, defined by that interface. In your case, it is only one method `actionPerformed`.
[UPDATE]

to read more about  `inner class` in java [This link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html)

Comment: I still dont understand how the 'new' keyword is written before ActionListener even though an annonymous inner class is being declared...

Comment: @falahmahmood An anonymous class *is* being created. You can tell by the `{ }` that appears right after the `()`. Look closely: `new ActionListener() { }`

Comment: Sorry bu the link did not help...can you tell me what will be the type of the listener variable on the first highlighted line?

Comment: @falahmahmood The variable type is declared when the variable is declared: `ActionListener listener` - it's of type `ActionListener`.

Comment: So this is what i am able to understand..it is alright to use the 'new' keyword before the ActionListener Interface AS LONG AS I am declaring an annonymous inner class which implements the Interface...Is my understanding correct??

Comment: AS LONG AS you will override abstract methods

Comment: The Interface will have abstract methods so ofcourse i will have to implement them myself...

Comment: @falahmahmood Yes, you can only use `new` with an interface (or abstract class) when creating an anonymous class.

Comment: Thankyou for the help